# normalizing Bayesian Network score

Tags: causality, bayesian-network, bic

I have been doing data driven `causal inference from Bayesian Networks in R` using `bnlearn` package on a random categorical dataset.
The data is used to learn the structure and parameters of model. 
Below is the code for learning structure of Bayesian network.

`boot_hc <- boot.strength(data = df, R = 100, m = nrow(df), algorithm = "hc", algorithm.args = list(score="bic"), cpdag = F, debug = T)`

`bn_hc <- averaged.network(strength = boot_hc, threshold = 0.85)`

The image below represents the learned structure[image]

The BIC score for the above DAG is `-339005.6` computed using

`> score(x = bn, data = df, type = "bic")
[1] -339005.6`

My question is

How can I normalize the BIC score (or any other score function) in order to get more understanding of quality of fit of learned structure ?